# Product of $2$ Taylor's Polynomials using little-$o$ notation

Tags: analysis, polynomials, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

We have $2$ functions, $f$ and $g$. Using Taylor's theorem:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_{k}(x-x_{0})^{k} + o((x - x_{0})^{n})$$

$$g(x) = \sum_{l=0}^{n}\beta_{l}(x-x_{0})^{l} + o((x - x_{0})^{n})$$

then product of $2$ functions is equal to:

$$f(x)g(x) = \sum_{k + l \le n }\alpha_{k}\beta_{l}(x-x_{0})^{k + l} + o((x - x_{0})^{n})$$

When I try to replicate it by multiplying both sides, I get:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x)g(x) =& \sum_{k + l \le 2n }\alpha_{k}\beta_{l}(x-x_{0})^{k + l} \\
 +& o((x - x_{0})^{n})\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_{k}(x-x_{0})^{k} \\
 +& o((x - x_{0})^{n})\sum_{l=0}^{n}\beta_{l}(x-x_{0})^{l} \\
 +& o((x - x_{0})^{2n})\\
\end{align}
$$

- because $k$ and $l$ is both $n$, $k + l = 2n$ for last element, therefore I applied $k + l \le 2n$ as condition instead of $k + l \le n$ as in original statement.

How can I prove these equations are equal? Thanks. [Source](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ehalas/MA/MA1/kopacek_-_mat._analyza_nejen_pro_fyziky_1.pdf#page=141) (p.$133-134$)

PS: I am not sure I understand this summation form, but I think it means this:

$$ \sum_{k + l \le n }\alpha_{k}\beta_{l}(x-x_{0})^{k + l} = \alpha_{0}\beta_{0} + \alpha_{1}\beta_{0}(x-x_{0}) + \alpha_{0}\beta_{1}(x-x_{0}) + ...$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to apply the definition of little-o. For every $k>n$ we have
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{(x-x_0)^k}{(x-x_0)^n}=0$$
and so $\displaystyle \sum_{n<k+l\leq 2n} \alpha_k \beta_l (x-x_0)^{k+l}=o((x-x_0)^n)$. A similar reasoning works for the remaining terms.

Comment: Thanks, with that approach I can get here: $$
f(x)g(x) = 
\sum_{k + l \le n }\alpha_{k}\beta_{l}(x-x_{0})^{k + l} 
 + o((x - x_{0})^{n}) 
 + o((x - x_{0})^{n})\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_{k}(x-x_{0})^{k}
 + o((x - x_{0})^{n})\sum_{l=0}^{n}\beta_{l}(x-x_{0})^{l} 
 + o((x - x_{0})^{2n}),$$ but how to solve the combination of the rest of little-o's to be equal to $o((x - x_{0})^{n})$?

Comment: Apply again the definition of little-o. We have $$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}\frac{o((x-x_0)^n)p(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}=0$$ for every polynomial $p$, and similarly $$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{o((x-x_0)^{2n})}{(x-x_0)^n}=\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}\frac{o((x-x_0)^{2n})}{(x-x_0)^{2n}}(x-x_0)^n=0$$